# Should I index the files each time I want to perform a search?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm storing logs locally in the folder `auditLogs` (it is located outside a server), in the following format:

[Name: uuid number]

```
[
  {
    "date": "2019-11-21T10:04:04.394Z",
    "user": "user",
    "action": "submit",
    "country": "US",
    "issueNumber": "1234",
    "environment": "TST"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-11-21T10:04:04.394Z",
    "user": "user",
    "action": "submit",
    "country": "US",
    "issueNumber": "1234",
    "environment": "TST"
  }
]
```

So in `auditLogs` folder, I've got hundreds of files that look like the one above.
Every day, some new files are adding to that folder.

Now, I'm trying to connect Elasticsearch for the searching purposes, should I index all files and send them to elasticsearch each time, I'm trying to make a search request?

Comment: You should only index the new documents since your last index, no need to index everything again.

Comment: You can use filebeat to constantly read updated content or new files in the folder and send them over to elastic as well.